# Float DIVs Side-by-Side within a 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a two column layout that has 'tiles' within the columns. These tiles are floating divs as well. The desired result is a very tabular layout without using tables.... Like so:

**Question:** Why in the linked fiddle is my first tile being rendered outside of my container divs?

```
<div class="column1"></div>
<div class="column2"> <!-- I am floating next to column1 -->
 <div class="tile-container">
  <div class="tile1"></div>
  <div class="tile2"></div> <!-- I am floating next to tile1 within column2 -->
 </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ExceptionLimeCat/KtDhX/)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking... Isn't `.SubTile{float:left}` enough?

Comment: BTW is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/KtDhX/1/

Comment: @otinanai Yes, but i need `column2` floating to the left of `column1`

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KtDhX/6/

Comment: @otinanai you essentailly led me to the correct answer. I added `float:left` to all of my classes including containers & tiles and that produced the desired effect. If you want to post that as the answer, I will accept.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat Glad I helped. Since you already answered it's OK by me to accept your own answer. After all I'm not here for the points.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/KtDhX/8/

I've added a `#wrapper` around your divs and gave it a 1000px width.
I've floated your second column left and your first right and floated both the tiles left so they won't leave their container.

Also try looking into `display: inline-block` to avoid the sometimes buggy behaviour of float and enables you to remove the `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by applying `float:left` to all container div's and tiles div's. This is per [CSS 2.1 Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).